# Using python requests is it possible to bypass adblock using request headers?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, adblock

I'm getting turn-off adblock messages from a website using `requests.get()` with default request parameters.

Would anyone be able to explain whether there is any way to specify adblock rules in the requests headers? For instance, adding a website exception as defined on https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet, the likes of:  `requests.get(url, headers={...adblock_rules = "@@||example.com^"...}`?

Comment: What is the website?

Comment: https://wyborcza.pl/7,75399,25974973,boris-johnson-broni-kluczowego-doradcy-ktory-zlamal-kwarantanne.html#S.koronawirus-K.C-B.1-L.1.duze. The text of```<div id="info-adblock">``` says 'In order to read our articles turn off Adblock/ublock or add an exception to our domain'

Comment: I think the typical pattern of websites like that is to ALWAYS include a div (like the one you mentioned) in the page code, and use a JS file that will typically get blocked by adblock to remove it. So your actual question is whether `python requests` can execute javascript.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. As far as I'm aware requests will not work to that end

Comment: I used requests-html package instead that supports JS as at https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/. Defining a session as ```session = AsyncHTMLSession()``` and then ```r = await session.get('https://wyborcza.pl/7,75399,25974973,boris-johnson-broni-kluczowego-doradcy-ktory-zlamal-kwarantanne.html#S.koronawirus-K.C-B.1-L.1.duze')
await r.html.arender()
resp=r.html.raw_html``` but I'm still getting the adblock message in resp. Would anyone have an idea why it's still not working?